# Do all 8 object tracking algorithms available in openCV need and Initial ROI?

Tags: python, opencv, object, image-processing, object-detection

I'm working on a project, where I have to detect colored cars that drive on railroads (small trains).

[image: 1]

For detection, I used histogram pack_projection to obtain a binary image that contains the car blob. Then drawing a bounding box is very straightforward. However, Since this is a detection which means the car is in every frame detected, I wanted to try to track the car and thus making the performance faster and with keeping track of the car ID( this means if the red car is now being traced and the car leaves from the image when the car goes back to the image and very oft from another place, the algorithm must track the car by indicating that this is the red car).

As you know, there are 8 object tracking methods in open CV, the code for them can be seen below:

```
import cv2

import sys



(major_ver, minor_ver, subminor_ver) = (cv2.__version__).split('.')



if __name__ == '__main__' :



# Set up tracker.

# Instead of MIL, you can also use



tracker_types = ['BOOSTING', 'MIL','KCF', 'TLD', 'MEDIANFLOW', 'GOTURN', 'MOSSE', 'CSRT']

tracker_type = tracker_types[2]



if int(minor_ver) < 3:

    tracker = cv2.Tracker_create(tracker_type)

else:

    if tracker_type == 'BOOSTING':

        tracker = cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()

    if tracker_type == 'MIL':

        tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()

    if tracker_type == 'KCF':

        tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()

    if tracker_type == 'TLD':

        tracker = cv2.TrackerTLD_create()

    if tracker_type == 'MEDIANFLOW':

        tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()

    if tracker_type == 'GOTURN':

        tracker = cv2.TrackerGOTURN_create()

    if tracker_type == 'MOSSE':

        tracker = cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create()

    if tracker_type == "CSRT":

        tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()



# Read video

video = cv2.VideoCapture("videos/chaplin.mp4")



# Exit if video not opened.

if not video.isOpened():

    print "Could not open video"

    sys.exit()



# Read first frame.

ok, frame = video.read()

if not ok:

    print 'Cannot read video file'

    sys.exit()

 

# Define an initial bounding box

bbox = (287, 23, 86, 320)



# Uncomment the line below to select a different bounding box

bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False)



# Initialize tracker with first frame and bounding box

ok = tracker.init(frame, bbox)



while True:

    # Read a new frame

    ok, frame = video.read()

    if not ok:

        break

     

    # Start timer

    timer = cv2.getTickCount()



    # Update tracker

    ok, bbox = tracker.update(frame)



    # Calculate Frames per second (FPS)

    fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer);



    # Draw bounding box

    if ok:

        # Tracking success

        p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]))

        p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))

        cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 2, 1)

    else :

        # Tracking failure

        cv2.putText(frame, "Tracking failure detected", (100,80), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75,(0,0,255),2)



    # Display tracker type on frame

    cv2.putText(frame, tracker_type + " Tracker", (100,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50),2);

 

    # Display FPS on frame

    cv2.putText(frame, "FPS : " + str(int(fps)), (100,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.75, (50,170,50), 2);



    # Display result

    cv2.imshow("Tracking", frame)



    # Exit if ESC pressed

    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff

    if k == 27 : break
```

**So my questions are:**
1- How can i make one of the above trackers detect a specific car that enters in a frame without having to select the ROI points with the mouse or by static pixel location
In other words, who can i orient one of the above trackers to track each colored if they exit the frame and re-enter after a while?

thanks in advance

Comment: does it re-enter at the same position where it did leave?

Comment: @Micka. I'm not sure what you mean. one enters the area to track, either by mouse or by defining the ROI in the image. Now when the car (the area that is being traced) leaves the frame, the search window stays in the last position when the car left. Thus, if the car re-enter the frame from an area different that the one if left from, no detection occurs